# how to use ubuntu official .ova image

Tags: ubuntu, vsphere

I downloaded the ubuntu image from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova, and deployed it to vmware vsphere. But I do not know the login credentials after the bootup.

So could someone tell me how to use the ova image? Is there a built-in default user?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when deploying the OVA, you will reach a screen where you enter the password or choose to use a random one, like the one below:
[image]

Did you by any chance input something in that field?